# Java/Mysql: Get all resulted lines from a stored procedure and not only the last

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in mysql that returns more than one lines.

[image]

My java code to execute it is:

```
preparedStmt = conn.prepareCall(queryString);
            preparedStmt.setString(1, String.valueOf(patient_id));
            //System.out.print("select patient data java file 1 ");

            boolean results = preparedStmt.execute();

            int rowsAffected = 0;
            // Protects against lack of SET NOCOUNT in stored procedure
            while (results || rowsAffected != -1) {
                if (results) {
                    rs = preparedStmt.getResultSet();
                    break;
                } else {
                    rowsAffected = preparedStmt.getUpdateCount();
                }
                results = preparedStmt.getMoreResults();
            }
            int i = 0;
            obj = new JSONObject();
            while (rs.next()) {
                JSONArray alist = new JSONArray();
                alist.put(rs.getString("patient_id"));
                alist.put(rs.getString("allergy"));
                alist.put(rs.getString("allergy_description"));
                alist.put(rs.getString("allergy_onset_date"));
                alist.put(rs.getString("agent_description"));
                alist.put(rs.getString("agent"));
                alist.put(rs.getString("severity"));
                obj.put("ps_allergies", alist);
                i++;
            }
            conn.close();
```

At the end, ps_allergies json object contains only the last line of the query. This is the print output:

```
["1","week",null,"2017-07-07","vacation home","test2","mobile contact"]
```

I want `ps_allergies` to contain something similar to

```
[["1","hydrogen peroxide","Nuts","2017-07-04","Nursing profressionals","43","Paramedical practinioners"],["1","week",null,"2017-07-07","vacation home","test2","mobile contact"]...]
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: The issue is here: `obj.put("ps_allergies", alist);`obj is map and you put all your lines in the map with the same key. Each result overwrites the previous one. That's why you only see the last line.

Comment: @StephaneM Yes I understand. Can have a separate line in a new list in json ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of **put** I'm using **append** method.

```
obj.append("ps_allergies", alist);
```

The resulted output now is:

```
[["1","hydrogen peroxide","Nuts","2017-07-04","Nursing professionals","43","Paramedical practitioners"],["1","chlorhexidine","test123","2017-07-15","mobile contact","test232","pager"],["1","Resistance to unspecified antibiotic","Feb3","2017-03-02","mobile contact","test232","pager"],["1","week",null,"2017-07-07","vacation home","test2","mobile contact"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly knowing what library you use, but it might have something to do with this line:
`obj.put("ps_allergies", alist);`

A put method in general associates the specified value with the specified key in a map. Since you are constantly overwriting you key 'ps_allergies' in the loop it will only retain the last value.

You might want to associate a list/array to ps_allergies and you then add every `alist` object in this list/array.

Comment: I want `ps_allergies` to contain something similar to `[["1","hydrogen peroxide","Nuts","2017-07-04","Nursing profressionals","43","Paramedical practinioners"],["1","week",null,"2017-07-07","vacation home","test2","mobile contact"]...]`